# geom_dotplot rounding decimal place of dot fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a boxplot of some data using ggplot2 in which I am displaying the data points as dots along the vertical axis of the plot.

```
bp2 <- ggplot(DBS, aes(DBS_Electrode,Proximal_Lead_Bowing, color=DBS_Electrode)) + 
    geom_boxplot() + geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="center", fill="white", 
    dotsize=0.5) + theme_classic()

bp2 + scale_color_manual(values=c("goldenrod3","gray62","dodgerblue1")) + 
    theme(legend.position = "none") + xlab("") + ylab("Proximal Lead Bowing (mm)")
```

It appears that my output is rounding the data points to the nearest tenth such that the data points along the axis of each boxplot have several instances in which multiple points are being displayed at the same level along the Y-axis (see plot http://rpubs.com/Gopher16/441664).  This is a misrepresentation of the data as there is are no data points that have the exact same measures of proximal lead bowing. (Data was measured to the nearest thousandth).  How can I change this output such that all data points are displayed along a vertical axis along each boxplot (i.e. read the data points to the nearest thousandth rather than rounding to the nearest tenth so that no points are displayed at the same level along the Y-axis)?

Comment: could I edit in the image from your RPubs link?  That way the image can be seen here and there's no risk of link breakage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's make this reproducible, and thus a more useful example for future readers, by using a built-in data set:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", fill = "white", dotsize = 0.5) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: horizontally adjacent points]

This exhibits the behavior you find unwanted: `geom_dotplot()` bins the points, making multiple points appear horizontally adjacent to each other even though their `Sepal.Length` values differ.

You could specify `binwidth = 0.01` or other small value to `geom_dotplot` but that's just reducing the problem, and introducing other issues.

You might want `geom_jitter` instead:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: jittered points]

This preserves the small differences in the unique y-values, which seems to be your chief concern.

Comment: Thank you for this!  This was extremely helpful

Comment: Glad it helped!  If you feel the problem is solved, you can mark the answer "accepted" by clicking the check mark.